# Is it possible to reset user defined data type by accessing the address typecasted content, in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to reset the values to 0 in the arrays made by user a defined data type and standard data type as in the code displayed below.

(Case 1)

```
 uint8_t source[2] = {1,1};
 uint8_t data[2];

typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t           event3;
    float32_t          event4;
    float32_t          event5;
} test_Data_ts;

test_Data_ts test_Data_s[32];

void main()
{
test_Data_ts test_Data_s2 = {0};

//This Works    
(*(uint32_t*)(data)) = 0;
(*(uint16_t*)(&data[0])) = (*(uint16_t*)(&source[0]));

//This Works
(*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = test_Data_s2; 
}
```

The following lines of code results in error 
 (Case 2)

```
(*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = *(test_Data_ts*)0x00; //do not execute
(*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = (test_Data_ts)0; //**Error -> conversion to non-scalar type requested   
(*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = 0;//**Error -> incompatible types when assigning to type 'test_Data_ts' from type 'int
```

Why is the second 3 cases are incorrect? Can somebody give explanations of the Errors as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])`
is the first element of table test_Data_s and is of type  `test_Data_ts`

In the first allocation, types are corrects.

```
 (*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = *(test_Data_ts*)0x00; //do not execute
```

but you are trying to dereference a null pointer.

```
(*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = (test_Data_ts)0; //**Error -> conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

It does not work, because you are asking the compiler to convert a scalar type (0 is `int`), to a `struct`.

```
 (*(test_Data_ts*)(&test_Data_s[0])) = 0;//**Error -> incompatible types when assigning 
              //to type 'test_Data_ts' from type 'int
```

You do not ask for a conversion, as in the previous line, but the compiler tells you that types on both sides of the assignment are not compatible. One is an `int` (0) and the other a `struct`.

Comment: typedef struct
{
    uint8_t MAC_ID[6];
} MacId_ts;
MacId_ts MacId_s[100];
uint8_t MacID_Found[6] = {0x20,0xCD,0x39,0xAA,0x2F,0xAD}; 
if(*((MacId_ts*)&MacId_s[0]) == *((MacId_ts*)MacID_Found))
//why this if conditional is going wrong?

Comment: Totally unrelated and you should ask another question. But in that case, you are trying to do a bitwise & between incompatible types. Maybe you meant && and different parenthesis?   `if((MacId_ts)&&((MacId_s[0]) == (MacId_ts)))`

Comment: It shares same concept, I'm typecasting and getting the content, and comparing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for

```
memset(&test_Data_s, 0, sizeof test_Data_s);
```